# move bitmap from (x,y) to (x2,y2) how to compute x,y values between start and destination

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to move a bitmap from point1 to point 2 using the angle?

```
x += speed * Math.sin(getAngle(pointDestination));
y += speed * Math.cos(getAngle(pointDestination));
```

edit:

```
public double getAngle(Point target) {
    double angle =  (Math.atan2(target.y - y, target.x - x));
    double angledeg = angle*0.0174532925;

    return angledeg;
}
```

Should getAngle() be executed on every iteration or just once at the beginning?
Unfortunately the sprite moves to a wrong direction.

Comment: I dont get it , you are answering your own question inside your question.

Comment: The code shows what i´ve tried but it doesn`t work.

Comment: sin and cos take in the angle in radians, is your getAngle returning degrees? if yes then multiply it by 0.0174532925  to convert it to radian

Comment: thank for the fast answers man, but it still doesn´t work. i´ll add the getAngle() method to the question right now.

Comment: whats your result? is the bitmap moving or it just stays still?

Comment: It is moving. But to a wrong direction.

Comment: You should rather use `Math.toDegree(angle)` for conversion. Won't solve your problem but avoids puzzled faces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you increment the x value and when you go to increment the y too you are using the new x that you just incremented to calculate the angle.
Change it to:

```
float angle=getAngle(pointDestination);
x += speed * Math.cos(angle);
y += speed * Math.sin(angle);

public double getAngle(Point target) {
    return Math.atan2(target.y - y, target.x - x);
}
```

Comment: @knecht ,check the answer i didn't realized that you are multiplying the radians that atan2 produces ....

Comment: Still a problem. The movement has changed now but i would say it got worse.

Comment: @knecht, Its working fine when I try it ,did you also swapped the cos and sin? you had it wrong ,cos is x and sin is y

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a incremental update of the bitmap position, you better define a (mathematical) function that computes the position (x, y) over time. The advantage is that this will result in very exact and predictable movements independent of CPU speed / frames per second.

Assuming that the bitmap should move at constant speed from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)` in `time` milliseconds, so your (time dependent) position functions are as follows:

```
x(t) := x1 + (x2 - x1) * t / time // t in range [0, time]
y(t) := y1 + (y2 - y1) * t / time // t in range [0, time]
```

(Note: By doing some physics/maths, you can define more sophisticated functions that result in more complex movements).

This two functions can then be used in your animation thread to update the position of the bitmap:

```
bitmap.setX(x(currentTime - animationStartTime));
bitmap.setY(y(currentTime - animationStartTime));
```

---

Have a look at [Trident animation library](https://kenai.com/projects/trident). It supports multiple UI frameworks and seems to be exactly what you're looking for!

---

**Update:** In case you really want to do a incremental update, e.g. based on your current frame rate, you don't need trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan, ...) at all, just vectors:

```
// x, y is the current position of the bitmap
// calculate vector (dx, dy) to target:
double dx = x2 - x;
double dy = y2 - y;

// calculate length of this vector:
double l = Math.hypot(dx, dy); // calculates sqrt(dx² + dy²)

// calculate unit vector of (dx, dy):
double vx = dx / l;
double vy = dy / l;

// update bitmap position:
// distance is the number of pixels to travel in this iteration (frame)
x += distance * vx;
y += distance * vy;
```

Note that all values should be of type `double`. Otherwise, if `int` is used for `x` and `y` and the increment is lower than 1 (e.g. due to slow movement, i.e. `distance` is very low), the bitmap won't move at all due to rounding errors!

Also note that in this approach you have to measure the frame rate to adjust `distance` accordingly to compensate deviation. The formula could be something like:

```
double distance = (time elapsed since last frame in sec) * (distance to travel per sec)
```

Comment: This seems to be a nice approach but i would like to do it with frames per second because the game generally works fine.

Comment: @knecht what do you mean by "i would like to do it with frames per second"?

Comment: the answer now also provides a solution using incremental update (without using sin/cos).

Comment: I will also try this approach later. Thank you!